# Postgresql choose between two selects and same value on different columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables

Person

| employeeNumber | name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EN12345 | Joe | Pilgrim |
| EN98764 | Eva | Snow |

Cashier

| employeeNumber | socialNumber | insuranceNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EN98764 | SN98764 | IN98764 |

Manager

| employeeNumber | socialNumber | insuranceNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EN12345 | SN12345 | IN12345 |

I need to join this tables into a new table Employee

| employeeNumber | name | last_name | socialNumber | insuranceNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EN12345 | Joe | Pilgrim | SN12345 | IN12345 |
| EN98764 | Eva | Snow | SN98764 | IN98764 |

I have no problem on the part of the name and last name, but I don't know how to do the rest. I have a vague idea, something like:

`SELECT cashier.socialNumber, cashier.insuranceNumber OR manager.socialNumber, manager.insuranceNumber FROM person INNER JOIN cashier ON person.employeeNumber = cashier.employeeNumber OR INNER JOIN manager ON person.employeeNumber = manager.employeeNumber`

I know this cannot be executed like this, but I  don't what to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two `left join`s:

```
SELECT COALESCE(c.socialNumber, m.socialNumber) as socialNumber,
       COALESCE(c.insuranceNumber, m.insuranceNumber) as insuranceNumber
FROM person p LEFT JOIN
     cashier c
     ON p.employeeNumber = c.employeeNumber LEFT JOIN
     manager m
     ON p.employeeNumber = m.employeeNumber;
```

If you have other types of people, you can add:

WHERE c.employeeNumber IS NOT NULL OR m.employeeNumber IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to union the two result sets like

```
SELECT p.employeeNumber, p.name, p.last_name, c.socialNumber, c.insuranceNumber
FROM person p
INNER JOIN cashier c ON p.employeeNumber = c.employeeNumber

UNION

SELECT p.employeeNumber, p.name, p.last_name, m.socialNumber, m.insuranceNumber
FROM person p
INNER JOIN manager m ON p.employeeNumber = m.employeeNumber

-- UNION
-- potentially more employee types
```

The difference with the `LEFT JOIN` approach is that in case an employee is *both* a cashier *and* a manager, it will be present in the result set twice.
If this is not desirable, you can de-duplicate the result set by using `UNION ALL`